# Randomize file names in a specified folder

Tags: python

I have a specific folder which contains files and I need to randomize their names. Folder location needs to be able to be changeable and file names should contain 6 - 10 characters from a - z. How can I do this in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The idea is to ask questions about your code, but since there's no code in the question it's likely it will be closed. Perhaps you can edit it with some code that you have tried?

Comment: Please clarify your issue - are you trying to rename the existing files in the given folder in a random way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to offer up pretty much the same answer as @user1929959's fine offering. The only difference is that my version varied the number of letters between 6 and 10.  So the actual line that produced the names in my version was:

```
newname = ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(randint(6, 10))])
```

UPDATE: I realize that maybe you wanted something different than the other answer...you wanted existing files renamed.  Here's the code that does that, except that I just print the rename operation rather than doing it so I can see what would happen without having to keep renaming back the files during testing.  You can change the print() line to a `os.rename()` call to actually do the renaming.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice, randint, random
import os

def randomize_files(dir):
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, f)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            newpath = os.path.join(dir, ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(randint(5, 8))]))
            # os.rename(path, newpath)
            print("rename {} to {}".format(path, newpath))

randomize_files("/tmp/tset21")
```

Result for my test dir with 4 files in it:

```
rename /tmp/tset21/bb to /tmp/tset21/idqjp
rename /tmp/tset21/dd to /tmp/tset21/zlyeflfa
rename /tmp/tset21/aa to /tmp/tset21/jjbvrm
rename /tmp/tset21/cc to /tmp/tset21/pkywyyz
```

Comment: How can I keep their extensions? For example 1.jpg to dsjsds.jpg. The script removes extensions.

Comment: that would be easy to fix.  Do you want me to update my answer?

Comment: Yes please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
 import string, random
 from random import randint
 import os, sys

 path = raw_input("Location of directory")
 nameDirectory = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in xrange(randint(6, 10)))
 pathDir = path + "/" + nameDirectory
 print "name of new directory with path " + pathDir
 os.mkdir( pathDir, 0755 )
```

Also in script you can read the permission for new created directory.